# prove the singularity of a matrix as solution of a non-linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fixed-point-theorems

Let $B$ ($n \times n$) and $R$ ($m \times m$) be two square matrix with $n>m>0$ who satisfie:

$B=(I-KH)B(I-KH)^T+K RK^T$

with $K=BH^T(HBH^T+R)^{-1}$ and $rank(H)=m$

I would like to prove $rank(B)\leq n-1$

(may be a weak version when $R=I_m$ )

Answer (score 2):

This is false.  Let H = m by n matrix of zeros. Then K = n by m matrix of zeros, and the first equation becomes B = B.  Any matrix B with rank > m is then a counterexample.

Here is a counterexample with n = 4, m = 2, valid even with your new requirement that rank(H) = m.

MATLAB output for the example is displayed. The output displayed is from the full internal accuracy of the matrices B,R,K.  svd(B) outputs the singular values of B, demonstrating it has rank 3.

```
>> disp(H)
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
>> disp(B)
  22.233617641547529 -26.649492704955527                   0                   0
  -0.085332888691858   0.102281069655391                   0                   0
                   0                   0   9.124565813043954 -90.929659197379337
                   0                   0 -90.929659197379493 -90.929659197379408
>> disp(svd(B))
   1.0e+02 *
   1.446855650880531
   0.628804717037176
   0.347065837843645
   0.000000000000000
>> disp(R)
 -87.754921322110661   1.996279186520130
 -83.098779133008037  99.999274211310279
>> disp(K)
  -0.001022739759789  -0.266476444364492
   0.000003925287350   0.001022739759789
                   0                   0
                   0                   0
>> B-((eye(n)-K*H)*B*(eye(n)-K*H)'+K*R*K')
ans =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
>> K - B*H'*inv(H*B*H'+R)
ans =
   1.0e-16 *
  -0.153956708492942  -0.555111512312578
  -0.001567010952420  -0.002168404344971
                   0                   0
                   0                   0
```

Comment: you are right, i  should add the condition $rank(H)=m$

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark L.Stone, do you think it holds for $rank(B)<n$, so have you found a full rank $B$ satisfies the equality?

Comment: I kept searching for a full rank (n) solution for B, and still have runs underway, but as yet have not found any. I am not sure full rank solutions don't exist, but if they do, they are much more difficult to find than rank > m solutions.I don't see any theoretical reason why full rank solutions don;t exist.

Comment: In the case n=2 and m=1 the maxima solver told me all solutions $B$ are of rank 1

Comment: After an extensive effort, I have now called off the search for a B rank n, H rank m solution. I still don't know whether such solution exists.